# SQL Server CTE on an Audit table to get the latest record

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression

ok this is a head wrecker and I will try to keep it brief.

I have two tables, Security and SecurityAudit
The Audit table keeps a copy of any changes to the Security table only if changes are made. The SecurityId is the Foriegn key. So the most recent record is always in the Security table and if there is a change then its written to the Audit table and the ValidToDate is set to the date the record was valid up to

```
[Security](
    [SecurityID] [bigint] IDENTITY(10000,1) NOT NULL,
    [Security] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ISIN] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [CountryOfIncID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SecurityTypeID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SubTypeID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ISQ] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [MemberStateID] [bigint] NULL,
    [ManualOverride] [bit] NULL,
```

here is the Audit table

```
[SecurityAudit](
          [SecurityAuditID] [bigint] IDENTITY(10000,1) NOT NULL,
          [SecurityID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
          [Security] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
          [CountryOfIncID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
          [SubTypeID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
          [ISQ] [bigint] NOT NULL,
          [MemberStateID] [bigint] NULL,
          [ValidToDateID] [datetime] Not NULL
```

So my problem is I now want to get all the securities that where in play at a particular point in time. This means get all the securities that have never had a change from the security table and then the relevant security from the Audit table for that point in time.

I thought I would do this using a CTE, and Union and a Rank but I,ve hit a wall. Its looking like this so far...

```
With
    cteAllSecurities (RowNum,SecurityID, Security, ISQ, CountryOfIncorporationID, ValidToDate)
    AS
    (
        SELECT RowNum=row_number() OVER (Partition By Security order by ValidToDate desc),
            sa.SecurityID, sa.Security, sa.ISQ, sa.CountryOfIncorporationID, CONVERT(varchar(30), sa.ValidToDate,106)
          FROM
            SecurityAudit sa 
        UNION 
        SELECT 0 as RowNum,
            s.SecurityID, s.Security, s.ISQ, s.CountryOfIncorporationID, CONVERT(varchar(30), GetUtcDate(),106) as ValidToDate
          FROM 
            Security s
    )
    SELECT RowNum, SecurityID, Security, ISQ, CountryOfIncorporationID, ValidToDate
    FROM cteAllSecurities
    order by securityid
    Where row_number() = 1
```

so I union the Securites table which has the last with the Audit and give them a row number. I was then hoping to get all the securities that have a row number of 0 and no child records... ie a child count of 0 in the audit table and the Audit Records that are less than the date I'm looking for and take the top one.

So I,ve got so far. Am I on the right tracks, over cooking it, or just plan mad. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you should be able to get the results you're looking for with a query such as this:

```
AllSecurity (Security, ISQ, CountryOfIncorporationID, ValidToDate)
AS (
    SELECT Security, ISQ, CountryOfIncID, CONVERT(DATETIME, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.997')
    FROM Security
        UNION
    SELECT Security, ISQ, CountryOfIncID, ValidToDate
    FROM SecurityAudit
)
SELECT TOP 1 Security, ISQ, CountryOfIncorporationID, ValidToDate
FROM AllSecurity A
WHERE ValidToDate = (
    SELECT MIN(ValidToDate)
    FROM AllSecurity B
    WHERE B.Security = A.Security
      AND ValidToDate > @SearchDate
)
```

You'll obviously want to replace `@SearchDate` with the value you're looking for.

This query will union the "current" security table, setting the ValidToDate to the maximum `DATETIME` value that SQL Server accepts, and unions it with the Audit Table.  Then, using a subquery, we get the "closest" (minimum) ValidToDate that's larger than the date we're looking at.

Comment: If it's possible to have two rows with the same ValidToDate, for the same SecurityId, in SecurityAudit, this solution could return them both.  It might be better to SELECT TOP 1 ... WHERE ValidToDate > @SearchDate ORDER BY ValidToDate.  Also, in the select list, you might want to return GETDATE() rather than ValidToDate if ValidToDate = '99999-12-31 23:59:59.997'  (use CASE or ISNULL(NULLIF...).

Comment: thanks galador... I think I'm on the right lines but yours looks a little bit slicker so I'll get a look into it. Have a look at mine below.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is what I have to date... Galador... i will get a look at yours also my friend as it looks better..  my only other concern is how performant this is... I dont expect the security table to be more that 30,000 records in a year and with around 300,000 Audits

```
With
    cteAllSecurities (RowNum,SecurityID, Security, ISQ, CountryOfIncorporationID, ValidToDate)
    AS
    (   -- Get all the securites and union the with the History records that we are interested in
        SELECT RowNum=row_number() OVER (Partition By Security order by ValidToDate desc),
            sa.SecurityID, sa.Security, sa.ISQ, sa.CountryOfIncID, CONVERT(varchar(30), sa.ValidToDate,106)
          FROM
            SecurityAudit sa 
          WHERE
            ValidToDate >= Cast('08-22-2011' as datetime)  -- filter out the records that we dont need
        UNION 
        SELECT 0 as RowNum,  -- make this Row num 0 so we can group on them
            s.SecurityID, s.Security, s.ISQ, s.CountryOfIncID, CONVERT(varchar(30), GetUtcDate(),106) as ValidToDate
          FROM 
            Security s
    ),
    cteMaxSecurties ( SecurityID, MaxValidToDate)
    AS
    (
        -- now get all the securities and find out their max date... 
        select SecurityID, Max(ValidToDate) from
            cteAllSecurities
          Group by SecurityID

    )   -- now join the max date and security
    SELECT RowNum, cteAllSecurities.SecurityID, Security, ISQ, CountryOfIncID, ValidToDate
    FROM cteAllSecurities Left Join cteMaxSecurties
            on cteAllSecurities.SecurityID = cteMaxSecurties.SecurityID and cteAllSecurities.ValidToDate = cteMaxSecurties.MaxValidToDate
    order by Security
```